# How to make Android TimePicker to show selected time?

Tags: android, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

Here is the Java code:

```
public class ReservationFragment extends DialogFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

private ReservationFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

private EditText fromDateEtxt;
private EditText fromTimeEtxt;


private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
private TimePickerDialog fromTimePickerDialog;

private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
private SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter;

public ReservationFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reservation, container, false);

    /** Date & Time Picker **/

    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.US);
    fromDateEtxt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.reservation_etxt6);
    fromDateEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    fromDateEtxt.requestFocus();

    timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.US);
    fromTimeEtxt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.reservation_etxt7);
    fromTimeEtxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    fromTimeEtxt.requestFocus();

    setDateField();
    setTimeField();

    return v;
}

private void setDateField() {

    fromDateEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);

    java.util.Calendar newCalendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            java.util.Calendar newDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            fromDateEtxt.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You choose: " + dayOfMonth + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

private void setTimeField(){

    fromTimeEtxt.setOnClickListener(this);

    java.util.Calendar newCalendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    fromTimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogTheme, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            java.util.Calendar newTime = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            newTime.set(hourOfDay, minute);
            fromTimeEtxt.setText(timeFormatter.format(newTime.getTime()));

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You choose: " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    },newCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), newCalendar.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE), false);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == fromDateEtxt) {
        fromDatePickerDialog.show();
    }
    else if(v == fromTimeEtxt) {
        fromTimePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Please, help me. Everything works fine, but I just want to put selected time in EditText NOT CURRENT TIME.

However I have to tell that my Toast works fine, it shows up selected time, but EditText not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the wrong values to `Calendar.set(int, int)`. Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int)).

It should be something like this:

```
java.util.Calendar newTime = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
newTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
newTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
fromTimeEtxt.setText(timeFormatter.format(newTime.getTime())
```

Comment: Thank You very much! You saved my day :)))